# UnicodeEncodeError at /upload/

Tags: python, django

For django file-upload I receive a UnicodeEncodeError at /upload/  with detail "latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position".

I thought python default codec is ASCII?  Where are the possible places where it could pick latin-1 up from?  My postgres is using utf8.

views.py:

```
        kind = Kind()
        kind.style = style
        kind.kind_file.save(request.FILES['file'].name,request.FILES['file'])
        kind.save()
```

models.py:

```
def get_upload_path(instance,filename):
    return u"tmp/%s" % filename

class Kind (models.Model):
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style)
    kind_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/django_projects/frogtype/frogtype/font/views.py" in upload_file
  56.                 kind.kind_file.save(request.FILES['file'].name,request.FILES['file'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  44.         name = self.get_available_name(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in get_available_name
  70.         while self.exists(name):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in exists
  230.         return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py" in exists
  18.         st = os.stat(path)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /upload/
Exception Value: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 87-88: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: Crystal ball broken. Try again later.

Comment: i edited it to be more clear.  i've been stuck on an encoding issue for a while and actually posted another related question.  i thought if i could figure out where the latin1 was coming from it may be a clue.  The context is I'm uploading a file and saving it with FileField

Comment: Is it from the same file being uploaded every time? Perhaps include a traceback to see where the error occurs.

Comment: i added the code and traceback , the filename is of type utf8

Comment: If latin-1 can't encode it, ascii certainly won't either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe latin-1 comes browser? (check default encoding and http headers in django)